# Get an entity with child collection filtered

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have an entity Position that has list of Good

```
Position
{
public int id { get; set; }
//other properties
public virtual ICollection<Good> Good { get; set; }
}

Good
{
public int id { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
public int positionId { get; set; }    
public virtual Position Position { get; set; }
}
```

So if I have:
Position 1
 Good 1, name = "A"
 
 Good 2, name = "A"
 
 Good 3, name = "B"

Position 2
Good 1, name = "A"
 Good 2, name = "D"

Position 3
Good 1, name = "C"
 Good 2, name = "D"

And search for Good with name = "A", it must return
Position 1
 Good 1, name = "A"
 Good 2, name = "A"
Position 2
Good 1, name = "A"

In other words - Position entities with List that contains only filtered Good.
How can I achieve this with minimum trips to database and minimum records loaded? Any tips are welcome

Comment: You say "Position 3
Good 1, name = "A"

In your example, there are no "Position 3" with name "A". I guess you mean Position 2 ?

Comment: @thomas, That is correct. Updated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well done! I see you use the proper Entity Framework method to model a one-to-many relation between Positions and Good. Every Position has zero or more Goods, and every Good belongs to exactly one Position.

The only advise I would give is to be consistent in your capitalization (PositionId instead of positionId) and use the plurals correctly: a Position has zero or more Goods (not: a Position has zero of more Good). Consistent usage of this makes reading your queries easier, which enhances maintainability. Besides usage of proper capitalization and pluralization minimizes the need for  Attributes and Fluent API.

So you want the sequence of all Positions that have at least one Good with Name equals "A", together with all its Goods that have this name.

I experience that once I've modeled the one-to-many relations correctly in entity framework I seldom use a join anymore. I think in collections that have zero or more items from other collections (Positions that have Goods), or Collections that are part of other elements (Goods that belong to a position). Entity Framework will translate this into a join.

Your query would be:

```
var result = myDbContext.Positions.Select(position => new                  
    {
        ... // use the Position properties you want in your result for example:
        Id = position.Id,
        // from the collection of goods, take only the goods with name equals "A":
        Goods = position.Goods.Where(good => good.Name == "A"),
    })
    // keep only those items that have at least one Good
    .Where(element => element.Goods.Any());
```

In words: From every position in the collection of Positions make one new ([anonymous type](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2012/06/21/c.net-little-wonders-the-joy-of-anonymous-types.aspx)) object with several properties:

- The properties you want from the Position. In your example this was something like "Position1"
- The sequence of all Goods from this Position that have a Name "A"

From the resulting collection keep only those elements that have at least one `Good`.

Entity framework will know that this is done using an SQL join / where / select

**Addition after comment: query without anonymous objects**

In the example above I created anonymous classes, because that is the easiest and most efficient if you don't want the complete objects. SQL will only do a select on the properties you request.

It might be that anonymous objects are not good enough for you. For instance you want to pass the result of the query to other functions, or you want the result in an object that has Methods and other Properties. In that case you can create a special class that contains the result.

Note that SQL does not know your special classes, so you can only use classes without constructor.

The Select in the query will slightly differ:

```
class SpecialPosition
{
     public int Id {set; set;}
     public string Name {get; set}
     public ICollection<SpecialGood> Goods {get; set;
}
class SpecialGood
{
     public int Id {set; set;}
     public string Name {get; set}
}
IEnumerable<SpecialPosition> result = myDbContext.Positions
    .Select(position => new SpecialPosition()                 
    {
        Id = position.Id,
        Name = position.Name,
        Goods = position.Goods
            .Select(good => new SpecialGood()
            {
                Id = good.Id,
                Name = good.Name,
            }
            .Where(speicalGood => specialGood.Name == "A"),
    })
    // keep only those items that have at least one Good
    .Where(element => element.Goods.Any());
```

Try for yourself what happens if you don't create SpecialPositions and SpecialGoods, but Positions and Goods

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Is there a way to achieve the same without using anonymous types? Is there a quick way to map the properties if there are many of them?

Comment: I like to see an answer which realizes that as long as the source is the original `IQueryable`, most LINQ-statements properly get translated to SQL properly. However, I'd like to point out that it is worth investigating the command it executes using SQL Server profiler or some similar tool. The reason for that is if you investigate it, you will see that the results actually get "flattened" (obviously, since its a relational model afterall). In other words, if entity A has two entity Bs, and you query that structure together, then what happens is...

Comment: ... that for each entity B participating in the relationship there will be one row, joined together with the requested columns from entity A - again - for every entity B. This is usually not a big deal, but if there are many entity Bs or some columns of entity A can be large (long comments, etc.) then this might cause performance problems. In such cases, I'd personally opt to 2 roundtrips instead, filtering for one part of the relationship, then select the Ids in my code (so not on the DB side) and filter the other side by the resulting id values.

Comment: While in most cases (again, when there aren't too many records or records with possibly large columns) saving roundtrips + cleaner code outweighs the little data redundancy it implies, it is something to consider in certain scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your database structure, this seems to be a problem that can be done with a simple Join: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Alternatively you could try to solve the problem with a linq GroupBy:

```
allPositions.SelectMany(p => p.Good)
.Where(g => g.name == "A")
.GroupBy(g => g.Position)
.ToDictionary(x => x.Key,x => x.ToList());
```

Comment: Yes, in SQL I can achieve this with a quite simple join. The problem is to write a proper LINQ query

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
list.Where(p => p.Good.Any(g => g.Name.Equals("A", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
```

(where the "A" should be replaced with a parameter)

Comment: I had this one, this gives the positions with full list of goods. I need it filtered